# User-defined binary types

Tags: haskell

I found this in The Monad.Reader issue 22:

```
data Color = R | B
data Node a = E | N Color (Node a) a (Node a)
type Tree a = Node a
```

Why not this instead?

```
data Node a = E | N Bool (Node a) a (Node a)
type Tree a = Node a
```

Comment: Because `Color` is much more explicit. Does `True` mean red or black?

Comment: @larsmans Just use comments.

Comment: Why use comments when you can use the type system?

Comment: @bheklilr Because I want not to use the type system.

Comment: Then why `Bool`? Why not 0 and 1? (Or 42 and 61?)

Comment: @larsmans Because `Bool` has exactly two values like `Color` and  I want to easily determine the color in if-then-else and guards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

larsmans said it all. Why use comments when you have the opportunity to render the code in a much clearer way without them? And don't forget that having `Color` also makes the distiction at type-level.

Moreover, imagine you would like to enrich the number of colors under consideration; then `Bool` would no longer be isomorphic to `Color`. Even though this isn't likely to happen in this particular piece of code, it is considered a general good practice. For instance, I reckon it is preferable to write `data WeekDay = Monday | Tuesday | ...` than say `type WeekDay = Int -- ranging 0..7`.

If I still haven't convinced you by this far, then please go ahead and use `Bool` instead. Let's just hope you'll never confuse which is which and lose your time around something that you could have avoided from the beginning.

Comment: The number of colors in a red-black trees isn't really going to change though.

Comment: I don't want to have the type-level distinction.

Comment: @ThePiercingPrince But you already have type-level distinction going on when using `Bool`, so that we might just as well call them "true-false trees" by now. As you've noticed, the two datatypes are isomorphic so there really is no theoretical advantage in using one or the other, it just boils down to more readable code.

Answer (score 5):

What would be the benefit of using `Bool` here? It's defined as `data Bool = False | True`, so it'll perform exactly the same; boolean operations don't make sense for `Color`.

EDIT: given the comment

> @bheklilr Because I want not to use the type system

the answer is that obviously the author of the article *did* want to use the type system. If you don't want to, nobody is forcing you to, but

1. it isn't clear why use Haskell at all in this case; the type system is one of its greatest strengths;
2. this is considered bad style in Haskell.